# How to compare selected id with country id in array and displaying its name not ID

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

My json response like this.

```
{
    "continent_code" = EU;
    "country_code" = al;
    "country_id" = 2;
    "country_name" = Albania; 
},
{
    "continent_code" = AF;
    "country_code" = dz;
    "country_id" = 3;
    "country_name" = Algeria;
},
```

My code is like this.

```
 country_selected=2; 
 NSMutableArray *wholeJsonArray = [LoginResult objectForKey:@"Response"];
    for(NSDictionary *countname in wholeJsonArray)
    {

        /* 
         NSString *cName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[countname     
         objectForKey:@"country_name"]];
         [countryArray addObject:cName];
         */


        NSString *countryName = [countname objectForKey:@"country_name"];
        if(countryName)
            [countryArray addObject:countryName];


        NSString *stateName=[countname objectForKey:@"state_name"];
        if(stateName)
            [stateArray addObject:stateName];
    }

    for(NSDictionary *cid in wholeJsonArray)
    {

        NSNumber *number = [cid objectForKey:@"country_id"];
        if(number)
            [idcountry addObject:number];

        NSNumber *statenumber=[cid objectForKey:@"state_id"];
        if(statenumber)
            [idstate addObject:statenumber];

    }
}
```

My question is that if user selected country id 2 then compare this value in array field and then display in title label is Albania.

So how can i do this output ?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> country_selected=2; 
> NSString *countryName;
> for(NSDictionary *countname in wholeJsonArray)
> {
>     NSNumber *country_id = [countname objectForKey:@"country_id"];
>     if(country_selected == country_id.integerValue){
>         countryName = [countname objectForKey:@"country_name"];
>     }           
> }
> ```

Where countryName will contain selected id country name;

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to find country from selected countryID

```
- (NSDictionary *)countryWithId:(NSUInteger)countryID
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country_id == %d",countryID];
    return [[self.wholeJSONArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]lastObject];

}
```

You can fetch country like

```
NSDictionary *country = [self countryWithId:2];
NSString *countryName = country[@"country_name"];
```

EDIT : OR

```
country_selected=2; 
NSMutableArray *wholeJsonArray = [LoginResult objectForKey:@"Response"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country_id == %d",countryID];
NSDictionary *country = [[wholeJsonArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]lastObject];
NSString *countryName = country[@"country_name"];
```